# XAML UserControl Triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Been stuck on this one for quite a while, not sure where I'm going wrong. I get the message

```
Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger.
```

I think my knowledge of triggers is correct and it is this type of trigger I need not an event trigger.

This is my mark-up

```
  <UserControl.Triggers>
     <Trigger SourceName="MainGrid" Property="Grid.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
         <Setter TargetName="DeleteButton" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#FF222222" />
     </Trigger>
 </UserControl.Triggers>
```

**Edit:**

It's not a fix but I have done this programmatically until I find how to solve this problem in XAML.

```
    private void MainGrid_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DeleteButton.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 34, 34, 34));
    }

    private void MainGrid_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DeleteButton.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 204, 204, 204));
    }
```

Comment: Try to use <i:EventTrigger EventName="IsMouseOver"> ...

Comment: Thanks but, unfortunately that doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the xaml below to the `UserControl.Triggers` section:

```
<EventTrigger SourceName="MainGrid" RoutedEvent="Grid.MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color">
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00">
                        <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="Red"
                                             KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>            
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger SourceName="MainGrid"
                      RoutedEvent="Grid.MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard >
                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color">
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00">
                        <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="Black"
                                             KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>            
        </EventTrigger>
```

Hope this helps.